# UML for Objective C class methods

Tags: objective-c, uml

If in UML `+` is used for public methods and `-` is used for private methods, how does one use UML for objective C methods that are class methods or methods that are public but object methods?

Comment: Today you are in mood to Thrash Obj-C :D

Comment: :) I thought its time to brush up on my higher level design knowledge and some questions have come up.

Comment: So you were waiting for overflowing of qustions...today is meant for that

Comment: Omnigraffle is a uml tool, check there, if you can find. I am not using mac, so i am searching in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public and private relate to instances, i.e. they are used for object methods.
Class methods are marked by underlining.